# How does visual composer render front-end inline custom css?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, visual-composer

I'm using a third-part plugin that allows a user to create a grid of posts and open a post in a lightbox (the posts have VC elements inside the lightbox). When adding any custom css to that page or custom design options to an element (background color, custom padding, margins or border), the front end doesn't render the custom css. I can see that it adds the custom css class to the element but the inline style doesn't get added.

How does VC create those inline styles? I looked through the vc docs but cannot find this resource. Any ideas how I can render the custom css in inline style?

Comment: You can add your custom css on any element as there is always some option available. The inline style is added with there javascript codes and the styles we select from backend/frontend editor;

Comment: @SahilDhir Right, that's what I'm saying – I add styles from the backend/frontend editor but the inline css for that page doesn't load on page render. Which js scripts do I need to make sure get enqueued that are responsible for rendering the inline styles?